# Make Android WebView not store cookies or passwords

Tags: android, cookies, oauth, passwords, webview

I use an [Android WebView for Twitter OAuth](https://github.com/sugree/twitter-android-sdk/blob/master/twitter/src/com/sugree/twitter/TwDialog.java): Twitter asks the user to log in and authorize the application, I retrieve the access token and persist it in my application.

I have no need (and do not) store the user password, but the WebView keeps Twitter's cookies around, and it also asks the user if he wants it to remember the password. As a result of this, even after the de-authorizes the application via his Twitter account page, and my application destroys the access tokens, the next time the WebView is opened, it is probably still logged in, and even if not, it has the password box already filled.

How can I force WebView to not ask to remember passwords, and to not persist session cookies?
If that is not possible, can I delete all its stored state (except maybe the image cache)?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use this to prevent cookies from being stored and clean cookies already stored:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookies(callback);
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);

WebView webview = new WebView(this);
WebSettings ws = webview.getSettings();
ws.setSaveFormData(false);
ws.setSavePassword(false); // Not needed for API level 18 or greater (deprecated)
```

Comment: Worked for me when I want to log out successfully in Twitter that uses WebView. Thanks. :)

Comment: Won't this just clear the cookies when the 3 lines are run? It doesn't prevent cookies from being stored. That would require something like `cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false)`. That said, this answers my question of how to clear cookies, so thanks.

Comment: Is the call to `CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);` needed?

Comment: @hooby3dfx, accordingly to the official documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.

If CookieManager.getInstance() is used before the application instantiates a WebView instance, CookieSyncManager.createInstance(Context) must be called first.

Comment: i just used this and getting error inside webview when trying to login using gmail  OOps your browser seems to have cookied disable.make sure cookies are enabled or try opening  new browser window

Comment: @CassioLandim  i just used this and getting error inside webview when trying to login using gmail OOps your browser seems to have cookied disable.make sure cookies are enabled or try opening new browser window

Comment: @Erum the trick for me was to just remove all cookies but not include the line `cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);`

Answer (score 33):

For not saving passwords:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
WebSettings mWebSettings = webview.getSettings();
mWebSettings.setSavePassword(false);
mWebSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
```

For cookies:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
```

I am not very sure for the cookies implementation.

Comment: Setting setSaveFormData(false) will also help.

Comment: @mudit, Not need to create a separate instance of `WebSettings`. You can also do this.

`WebView webView = new WebView(this);`
`webView.getSettings.setSavePassword(false);`

Comment: Be careful with `.setSavePassword` function since it is deprecated for version 4.4 and higher : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19361928/62921 On those version it will be false by default and the popup will not promp.

Answer (score 11):

This is the best answer I have seen in this context

```
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false); // Not needed for API level 18 or greater (deprecated)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    } else {
        CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
        cookieSyncMngr.sync();
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

In one line, Try this. I think this should be called after starting the webview.

```
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't clear cookies beacause it will effect other sessions like facebook etc.. stored inside the cookie so try to follow this method

Before oauth transaction such as before the webview creation

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
```

After oauth transaction let accept cookie by setting

```
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
```

it will work i have tested it..

Answer (score 1):

I have used following solution:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
```

Following method does not worked for me:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

A possible reason may be that we have not synced the cookies as following:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext()).sync();
```

But it may be taking time.

Forcing `WebView` to not ask to remember passwords will also not work.

And it is also not good for usability.