# Disable Android browser 'Save Password' functionality through the code

Tags: android, android-webview, android-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable the “save password” dialog on an Android WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531778/how-to-disable-the-save-password-dialog-on-an-android-webview)

Is there any way to disable the "save password" functionality on the android browser through the program.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to disable the “save password” dialog on an Android WebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11531778/645270)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), regarding to the documentation there is **no way** to disable this functionality.

Update: Keyser added a [link that shows how to disable password saving from within the WebView.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11531778/645270)

Comment: My application uses browser, but thanks for the link i did not know that it is working for web view.