# Remove cookies for a particular list of domains in webview android

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-studio

In my android application I have a webview. It loads URLs from multiple domains. I need to delete all cookies from a specific domain. I want to keep cookies from other domains. But I need to delete all cookies from one domain.

How could I implement this. Please give a code snippet so that I can understand as I have read solutions on stackoverflow but not able to understand.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404274/make-android-webview-not-store-cookies-or-passwords

Comment: But this is not domain specific. It will remove other as well. Actually I am using google analytics as well in my website which I am showing in the webview. Thats why I want to specifically remove cookie for particular domians.

Comment: public abstract String getCookie (String url): Use this to get cookies from Google Analytics,  then, remove all coookies and then, set cookie for analytics using public void setCookie (String url, String value, ValueCallback<Boolean> callback).