# Cordova Plugin to access WebKit CookieManager?

Tags: cordova, cookies, webkit, android-cookiemanager

In my cordova project, I need to call Android's WebKit CookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false) in order to pass a security audit which flags the session cookie as plain text on the device.

I've been able to proof this solution by editing the generated CordovaActivity.onCreate() to turn off cookies as per [Make Android WebView not store cookies or passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404274/make-android-webview-not-store-cookies-or-passwords/6389667#6389667)

We are using build.phonegap.com to assemble our app so editing the CordovaActivity is not a viable solution (unless I am wrong).

I found this interface, [ICordovaCookieManager](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/ICordovaCookieManager.java), which seems to abstract the WebKit CookieManager but I could not find a plugin that connects it to javascript.

Is there a plug-in or other javascript interface to the Webkit CookieManager?