# How to enable cookies in android webview?

Tags: android, webview

How do I enable cookies in a webview?

I tried to use

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

just before calling WebView.loadUrl() and it doesn't work as I get an HTML page error from a website saying cookies need to be enabled.

How does cookieManager know which webview to enable cookies?

Say if I had an activity with two webviews in the screen and I only wanted one of those webviews to enable cookies, how is that possible using a CookieManager?

I feel like I am missing something. I could not find a method like webView.setCookieManager or Cookiemanager.setWebView(webview).

Comment: Setting `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` is useless because setAcceptCookie() is true by default: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#setAcceptCookie(boolean) Cookies in your case maybe were not working because of not enabled `CookieManager#setAcceptThirdPartyCookies` or  `CookieManager#setAcceptFileSchemeCookies`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`CookieManager.getInstance()` is the *CookieManager* instance for your entire application.
Hence, you enable or disable cookies for all the *webviews* in your application.

Normally it should work if your webview is already initialized:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#getInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#getInstance%28%29)

Maybe you call `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` before you initialize your *webview* and this is the problem?

Comment: My problem is that the webview does not send the cookie already living in the store. How do you make webview send the cookie? I am initializing webview after `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` Am I missing something?

Comment: Also check this answer for API >21 (post Lollipop):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47868677/3101777

Comment: Setting `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` is useless because setAcceptCookie() is true by default: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#setAcceptCookie(boolean)

Answer (score 51):

You should consider that

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

doesn't work from lollipop(API21)  and above. You should check and use appropriate function for that case:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {   
     CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
} else {
     CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do `WebView`'s accept cookies by default? I imagine they would, right?

Comment: Where do you see that setAcceptCookie doesn't work when >= 21? It's not listed https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptCookie(boolean)

Comment: Answer is wrong. You can not use if/else. Use `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` without condition to enable cookies and use `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) { CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true); }` to enable also 3rd party cookies. However first part is not needed at all because setAcceptCookie() is true by default: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#setAcceptCookie(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
    } else {
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)
            }
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView.settings.databaseEnabled = true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).