# Session not supported on Android browser

Tags: php, android, session-cookies

I have built a web app that works great on my computer browser i am using

```
        session_start();
```

and i am assigning data to the session from a html form like

```
    $game=$_SESSION['gamecode'];
```

Like i said it works great on my computers browser However not on my android phone.
It is also not working on my acer a 200 tablet either.

I must be missing something that i need to make android store the cookie.
thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think problem is with `php sessions` here

Comment: Would you kindly please let me know where the issue might be?

Comment: I have no idea, but I believe php sessions have nothing to do with devices, however cookies might

Comment: Ya i was thinking it was the cookies too...

Comment: Please try this , it might help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230757/how-to-enable-cookies-in-android-webview

Answer (score 0):

My problem was on server-side the session.save_path not definied to my server. Might be this will help you