# getting white page in webview after facebook login page success

Tags: android, android-webview, android-facebook

I am creating an app, which will post string to the facebook wall. For this , am using a remotely placed html with javascript methods for posting to facebook. It works fine in desktop and mobile browsers.But am getting white screen in android webview.

Link for html page is this,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2anle06yh9sdcn7/my_fb_post_log.html

and android project is placed in ,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9an2w2bd9i6nm7f/TestShare.zip

Can anyone please help me on this ? Facebook application id is private, hope you have to create new one for testing that.

Thanks in advance,
JRH

Comment: Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable cookies for webView component. Refer following link

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230757/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230757/how-to-enable-cookies-in-android-webview)