# CSRF token is "undefined"

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, csrf

I am using an Android WebView to call a JavaScript function. Basically, I'm calling the JavaScript function in the onClickListener of a button. The function is called. In the function I'm trying to send a POST request to a remote server. The POST request is of a sign-up form. However, I'm not able to set the csrf token in my JavaScript code. I have of course set INTERNET PERMISSION in my manifest file. The console.log(csrftoken) gives "undefined" and hence I'm not able to set it as the header in my ajax call. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

```
<body>
<h1>MyHTML</h1>


<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">


 function onClickSignUp(username,email,password) {
            console.log("trying to signup");
            var signup_url = 'http://ec2-54-165-136-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com/accounts/signup/';

            var html = "You have been registered! Thank You";


            var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
            console.log("csrf token");
            console.log(csrftoken);
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend : function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : signup_url,
                data : {
                    "email" : email,
                    "fullname" : username,
                    "password1" : password,
                    "password2" : password
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(json) {
                    console.log("success");
                    updateView("big-signup-signin-viewer", json, html);
                },
                error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    // console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                    // console.log("Status: " + status);
                    // console.dir(xhr);
                    // console.log(xhr.responseJSON.form_errors.email[0]);
                    //var html_text = xhr.responseJSON.form_errors.__all__[0] + "<a href='/accounts/password/reset/' ><p>Forgot Password?</p></a>"
                    $("#signup-error").html(xhr.responseJSON.form_errors.email[0]);
                },
                // code to run regardless of success or failure
                complete : function(xhr, status) {

                }
            });

            function updateView(id, json, newview) {
                console.log("updating with new view");
                console.dir(json);
                //document.getElementById("landing_page").outerHtml = newview;
                //$("#landing_page").html("you have signed up");
                // notify user that she/he has been signed up and ask to confirm email
                window.location.replace("/posts/");
            }

            return false;
        };
```

This is the logcat:
This is the logcat:

11-21 23:57:30.834: I/chromium(17610): [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "csrf token", source: file:///android_asset/mypage.html (25)
11-21 23:57:30.834: I/chromium(17610): [INFO:CONSOLE(26)] "undefined", source: file:///android_asset/mypage.html (26)
11-21 23:57:30.843: D/audio_hw_primary(183): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
11-21 23:57:30.854: D/audio_hw_primary(183): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
11-21 23:57:30.854: D/msm8974_platform(183): platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
11-21 23:57:30.854: D/audio_hw_primary(183): enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
11-21 23:57:30.859: D/audio_hw_primary(183): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
11-21 23:57:31.362: I/chromium(17610): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec2-54-165-136-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com/accounts/signup/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.", source: file:///android_asset/mypage.html (0)
11-21 23:57:31.366: I/chromium(17610): [INFO:CONSOLE(54)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form_errors' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/mypage.html (54)
11-21 23:57:34.020: D/audio_hw_primary(183): disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
11-21 23:57:34.021: D/audio_hw_primary(183): disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)

Comment: Have you [enabled cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230757/how-to-enable-cookies-in-android-webview) in your webviews?

Comment: Yes, I have.. I do not get any cookie error either.