# Android Studio: Showing web page that requires login in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, jsoup

I try to show part of a webpage using webview and the SELECT function of Jsoup.
It works when we select a class from a regular HTML page and then do a "loadData" to the WebView.
However, if the page has login it doesn't show anything.
Even, if we try to login first using "loadURL" into the WebView and logging in with the user and password, and only then do a "loadData" to the same page it doesn't work.
Is there an example showing how to handle pages that have login?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not properly logging you in is because you don't store cookies with your Webview. When you login, there's likely a session cookie stored that authenticates the user. If it's not enabled, the user can't stay logged in between pages.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230757/how-to-enable-cookies-in-android-webview) on how to enable cookies in a webview. You are using the `CookieManager` in android to do this.

Comment: I don't think it's related to cookies becasue using loadUrl to the webview does remember the login automatically. I think that the problem is because when I apply the SELECT jsoup function on the URL in order to eventually load it by loadData to the webview, the code that the select works is not the actual web page after login but the page of the login before it automatically redirects due to the stored cookie. Is this correct? How can I solve this?