# If the WebView in my Xcode app works why would it not work in my Android app?

Tags: php, android

Today I started my first android app using "Android Studio". I have created a WebView app that displays a PHP scripts which has a HTML form with one input field and a submit button. Once the correct user code is entered the PHP script checks if the user code is correct. If correct opens another PHP script displaying data. At least that what it should do.

I already have a App written in Mac Xcode which works as expected and accessing the PHP using a browser works find.

The PHP script using PHP SESSION variables but the Android app does not seem to like them.

Comment: @PietroSaccardi many thanks. I have now managed to get this working. All I needed was a pointer which you kindly provided.

Comment: I reposted as answer, it may be good for future reference; it is not immediate to think about cookies when WebView just seems to misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to how cookies are handled by Android's WebView.

By default, cookies are not enabled, therefore even if PHP tries to store the `session_id`, it cannot retrieve it later, and this causes a new session to start.

On SO you can find many answers that explain you how to enable cookies for WebView. See for example this one: [How to enable cookies in Android WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230757/how-to-enable-cookies-in-android-webview).