# Android: How to enable cookies in android webview.?

Tags: android, webview

i need to enable cookies in android WebView. in my WebView application not loading some websites .showing Error message

> "Unable to send the cookie. A maximum number of cookies would be
>   exceeded."

one of my friends told me to enable cookies in WebView how i do that.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230757/how-to-enable-cookies-in-android-webview

Comment: For full solution, check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47868677/3101777

Answer (score 1):

Add this code after you initiallize your webview

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

Comment: Also, consider full solution  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47868677/3101777