# Codename One How to disable cookies in BrowserComponent

Tags: codenameone

I have added a payment method (called [fawry](https://developer.fawrystaging.com/docs/get-started)) in my app by using HTML code in browser component and all things are working fine in simulator but when testing that on a real device, i faced this problem:

[image: error image]

**How I can fix this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google changed the way cookies are handled in the WebView in newer versions according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47868677/756809

I made a fix for this so cookies will be on by default in this commit: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/7d65d9ee0e20035b6d86807ec1cb1bfc077446af

Comment: Thanks! How I can use this commit in the current version? or when will this update be available?

Comment: This should be out next week on our regular Friday releases. You can also build from sources using Maven. There's a blog post about it from Steve from a while back.