# cookies need to be enabled in webview in dotnetmaui blazor app for it to work

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core, maui-blazor

I have the following plan in my dotnet blazor maui project

1. The user enters his username and password on the login razor component.
2. It calls the web api in question
3. it set the cookies in the web api
4. and returns the cookie to the browser

it worked in my blazor web assembly app. but same code is not working in maui app

do i need to enabled cookies in webview to make it work. how can i enabled cookies in webview if so?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the platform native to enable the WebView Cookie in the maui blazor. Such as:

In the MainPage.xml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DisableF5"
             x:Class="DisableF5.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
    <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorwebview" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>
```

And in the MainPage.cs:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
      {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS  
            var webview = blazorwebview.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2;
            var cookie = webview.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookie();
            webview.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie();
            webview.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.GetCookiesAsync();
#elif ANDROID
        var webview = blazorwebview.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
        Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptCookie(true);
            Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview,true);
#endif
      }
```

For the windows platform, I refer to [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3901#issuecomment-1150322720) in the existed issue on the github which is about [Cookies read/write not working in WebView on WinUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3901).

And for the android & ios, there is also an known issue which is about WebView Cookies not working(https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12896) and you can follow up the [Reinstate WebView cookie functionality for Android & iOS](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/13736).

And the android platform native code I refer to [How to enable cookies in android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230757/how-to-enable-cookies-in-android-webview)