# Web Api using Google authentication on Android / IOS

Tags: android, azure, asp.net-web-api, webview, oauth

I followed the following [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358918/4838107) on how to set up Web API with Google authentication.

Basically the Azure page has to redirect to Google and the Google login has to redirect back to an Azure page that gives an access token that I can put in a header to get data specific to that Google Account.

It works on Android when I use a WebView but apparently this is frowned upon for security issues and on IOS, Google blocks me from entering a password.

So my question is how do I do the same thing but without using a WebView? I tried implementing Google+ Sign In but I was only able to retrieve an authentication token and I don't know if this is useful at all.