# Web Api 2 external providers authenticate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have asp.net web api authentication with external providers and asp.net mvc application. I want to authenticate from the mvc app. I follow instructions from this post: [asp.net web api 2: how to login with external authentication services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065648/asp-net-web-api-2-how-to-login-with-external-authentication-services) but how can i get the access_token after redirect from provider page?

Comment: Did you look into the header of the response ? should be there

Comment: It isn't there, it is in redirect url.

Comment: You want to know how to extract the token from the url ? How to parse the query string ?