# Do I need to worry about refresh tokens using Facebook external login in Web API?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have an ASP.NET Web API project, and recently added both local and external OAuth login (using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065648/asp-net-web-api-2-how-to-login-with-external-authentication-services) as a base). Now, the login is working, but what I worry about now is the expiration date of the tokens. If I understand correctly, Facebook's tokens expire after [60 days](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension), so that means that after two months I should be refreshing the tokens.

But, now my question is, does ASP.NET Web API handle this refresh process for me? Or do I have to add my own logic? I ask because the tutorials are not clear about what to do. They just tell you to enable the Facebook auth and that's it.

Comment: No server-side API can "refresh" user access tokens on its own, because that requires user interaction. The user has to at least visit your app in a browser while being logged in to Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe Do you know how to do that in Web API?

Comment: If you embed the JS SDK, it will recognize a recurring user automatically. You can then either send the access token to the server, or try and fish the information out of the cookies it sets.

Comment: @CBroe Does this also apply to a Cordova app as well?