# C# Web Api 2 Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying Facebook Login for Web Api project. When try to call "`api/Account/RegisterExternal`", it is getting `InternalServerError` due to NULL return in info at `var info = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();`
I'm using Postman to try as following steps. Could anyone please advise which step I'm missing?
the project is using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook 4.2.0 with .net framework 4.7.2

Step 1:
GET Request
url-

```
https://localhost:44381/api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
```

Response-

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Facebook",
        "Url": "/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44381%2F&state=3aRj6cMG4pJ3Zbc748Pi7iGiFmeUZVZdAN9vjks4S9g1",
        "State": "3aRj6cMG4pJ3Zbc748Pi7iGiFmeUZVZdAN9vjks4S9g1"
    }
]
```

Step 2:
Get Request in Browser

```
https://localhost:44381/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44381%2F&state=3aRj6cMG4pJ3Zbc748Pi7iGiFmeUZVZdAN9vjks4S9g1
```

Step 3: Fill in the Facebook login credential at browser and submit. It will redirect to

```
https://localhost:44381/#access_token=4s0GvYI05PK6Ko-El36scfeuwb6ICaFEsck8bCZU605w-U-lKx-BkH2U2FYdWO4Z92tgltHJWF2wYlul4IMt7ON9ZKz1BeHC0K2X0oyuvWU3aBJbt3ZzG7NoEmgiAbipTbhXuj9txEx5DGiJ2UELA42Yxb8NkNHnG6ih43vFB&token_type=bearer&expires_in=1209600&state=3aRj6cMG4pJ3Zbc748Pi7iGiFmeUZVZdAN9vjks4S9g1
```

Step 4: Copy the accesstoken from redirect url

Step 5: GET request url-

```
https://localhost:44381/api/Account/UserInfo
Header: 
Content-Type application/json
Authorization bearer {accesstoken}
```

Response

```
{
    "Email": "email@example.com",
    "HasRegistered": false,
    "LoginProvider": "Facebook"
}
```

Step 6: POST Request

```
https://localhost:44381/api/Account/RegisterExternal
Header: 
Content-Type application/json
Authorization bearer {accesstoken}

Body: 
{
  "Email": "email@example.com"
}
```

Comment: If these web api calls were used via JavaScript Ajax call from HTML page, it is working fine. But encounter error when call separately via Postman or C# web client.

I've created the sample web api project with login page and posted in GitHub.
[https://github.com/SuMingYuan-MM/WebApiTest](https://github.com/SuMingYuan-MM/WebApiTest)

need to add Facebook Client Id and Credential and call https://localhost:44381/login.html to do testing.