# Social Login: How to logout of Instagram. How to clear Web View username and password?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, social-networking

I have tried removing cookies and clearing history from `WebView` but cannot able to logout completely.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    view.clearHistory();
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    String title = mWebView.getTitle();
    if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
        mTitle.setText(title);
    }
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
    Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished URL: " + url);
    mSpinner.dismiss();
}
```

and setting up `WebView`

```
private void setUpWebView() {
    mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new OAuthWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    mWebSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    mWebView.clearView();
    mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
    mWebView.clearCache(true);
    mWebView.clearHistory();
    mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
    mContent.addView(mWebView);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    //cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below method to clear cookie for every login. [`removeAllCookie`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#removeAllCookie()) method was deprecated in API level 21. Use [`removeAllCookies(ValueCallback)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#removeAllCookies(android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.Boolean%3E)) instead.

```
// Clear cookie to prevent automatic login
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  private void clearCookie() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
      } else {
          CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
      }
  }
```

This should also work

```
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);

webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
```

Comment: the data (username, password) in webview is not cleared

Answer (score 1):

`CookieSyncManager` is marked as deprecated,

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html)

and here is the method

> public abstract void removeAllCookies (ValueCallback callback)

In your case:

```
cookieManager.removeAllCookies(null);
```

Should be like this

```
android.webkit.CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
           // for  >21 devices
           cookieManager.removeAllCookies(null);
     }
      else 
      {
        // for  <21 devices 
       cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
       }
```

If with "null" it doesn't work, then you have to use a callback*. like below

```
 android.webkit.CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
           // for  >21 devices
           cookieManager.removeAllCookies(new ValueCallback<Boolean>() {
             // a callback which is executed when the cookies have been removed
             @Override
             public void onReceiveValue(Boolean aBoolean) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Cookie removed: " + aBoolean);
             }
           });
     }
      else 
      {
        // for  <21 devices 
       cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
       }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have tried it in onPageFinished , but its not workin g

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566485/webview-and-cookies-on-android