# Android WebView app is not saving Cookies

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

The webview app is not saving cookies, but all other browsers, both PC and Android saved login data.
Cookies are not getting saved I guess. Each time the app is closed, the logged in details are not getting saved.
I am new to app development, I cant figure out how to fix this issue.
Here is the full source link

https://github.com/shylendramadda/android-webview-kotlin

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Log
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.webkit.*
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var progress: Progress? = null
    private var isLoaded: Boolean = false
    private var doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false
    private var webURL = "https://www.nextinweb.com/"

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val settings = webView.settings
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.allowFileAccess = true
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        settings.supportMultipleWindows()
        progress = Progress(this, R.string.please_wait, cancelable = true)
        if (!isOnline()) {
            showToast(getString(R.string.no_internet))
            infoTV.text = getString(R.string.no_internet)
            showNoNetSnackBar()
            return
        }


    }


    override fun onResume() {
        if (isOnline() && !isLoaded) loadWebView()
        super.onResume()
    }

    private fun loadWebView() {
        showProgress(true)
        infoTV.text = ""
        webView.loadUrl(webURL)
        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                val url = request?.url.toString()

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
                } else {
                    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
                }

                if (url.contains("facebook.com") || url.contains("twitter.com") || url.contains("instagram.com") || url.contains("youtube.com")) {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                    startActivity(intent)
                    webView.goBack()
                    return true
                } else {
                    view?.loadUrl(url)
                }


                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
            }


            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                showProgress(true)
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                isLoaded = true
                showProgress(false)
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            }

            override fun onReceivedError(
                view: WebView,
                request: WebResourceRequest,
                error: WebResourceError
            ) {
                isLoaded = false
                val errorMessage = "Got Error! $error"
                showToast(errorMessage)
                infoTV.text = errorMessage
                showProgress(false)
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
            }
        }
    }



    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack()
                } else {
                    showToastToExit()
                }
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }

    private fun showToastToExit() {
        when {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce -> {
                onBackPressed()
            }
            else -> {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true
                showToast(getString(R.string.back_again_to_exit))
                Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed(
                    { doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false },
                    2000
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showProgress(visible: Boolean) {

    }

    private fun isOnline(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            when {
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR")
                    return true
                }
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI")
                    return true
                }
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET")
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun showToast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun showNoNetSnackBar() {
        val snack =
            Snackbar.make(rootView, getString(R.string.no_internet), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        snack.setAction(getString(R.string.settings)) {
            startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
        }
        snack.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebView and Cookies on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566485/webview-and-cookies-on-android)

Comment: @DarShan , No, I am not asking how to save cookies in webview, i have the code, but they are not working. I want experts to take a look at it and suggest changes.