# Set a cookie to a webView in Android

Tags: android, http, cookies, post

I'm getting a `HttpResponse` from a server when checking if a username or password is correct.
When I load the `url` in a `webview` I want the `webView` to have the cookie (the answer I get with `postData()` stored in the `webView`.
I want the webView to pickup the cookie and load the url with that cookie stored in the webview.

I'm getting the response through.

```
public HttpResponse postData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://example.com/login.aspx");

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUsername", "user"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtPassword", "123"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseAsText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.v(TAG , "Response from req: " + responseAsText);
        return responseAsText;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

And I loadUrl with:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://a_page.com/getpage.aspx?p=home");
```

I guess I'm not really managing a cookie and I have no idea how to do so.
Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566485/webview-and-cookies-on-android

Comment: Android documentation for webView CookieManager is  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android WebView Cookie Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem)

Answer (score 35):

It's quite simple really.

```
String cookieString = "cookie_name=cookie_value; path=/";
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(baseUrl, cookieString);
```

where `cookieString` is formatted the same as a more traditional `Set-Cookie` HTTP header, and `baseUrl` is the site the cookie should belong to.

Comment: Finally I found a solution for this, many thanks George. Quick question. Do you know what would be the duration of the cookie in this way? or what would be the parameter to set it?

Comment: This is a session cookie, so it probably expires when the application is closed. To make the cookie permanent, you would add the Expire rule to set a definite end date. Search online for how to add Cookie Expiration. If you have issues putting this in place, feel free to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a detailed question with a code sample.

Comment: Note `setCookie()` accepts only a single cookie value, for multiple cookies check https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159942/12173451

Answer (score 19):

Couple of comments which I found out from my experience and gave me headaches:

1. `http` and `https` urls are different. Setting a cookie for `http://www.example.com` is different than setting a cookie for `https://www.example.com`
2. A slash in the end of the url can also make a difference. In my case `https://www.example.com/` works but `https://www.example.com` does not work.
3. `CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie` is performing an asynchronous operation. So, if you load a url right away after you set it, it is not guaranteed that the cookies will have already been written. To prevent unexpected and unstable behaviours, use the CookieManager#setCookie(String url, String value, ValueCallback callback) ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#setCookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.Boolean%3E))) and start loading the url after the callback will be called.

I hope my two cents save some time from some people so you won't have to face the same problems like I did.

Comment: The documentation says that the setCookie method with the callback parameter is asynchronous, but it doesn't say that about the one without the callback parameter. Is that one asynchronous? If so, how do you know that?

Comment: Setting the cookies without the callback was inconsistent for me. The cookies were sometimes set right away, sometimes not. Trial & error, having the chrome debug tool open in the desktop Chrome browser and triggering a toast in my app which was displaying the currently set cookies of my webview.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I ended up just passing a URL parameter to the server and having the server handle the logic and cookie setting.

Answer (score 5):

You should use it with some loop if you have few items with cookies (like in my case):

```
val cookiesList = listOf("key1=someValue1", "key2=someValue2", "key3=someValue3")
cookiesList.forEach { item ->
 CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie("http://someHost.com", item)
}
```

You **can't** use it like:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie("http://someHost.com", "key1=someValue1;key2=someValue2;key3=someValue3")
```

Answer (score 5):

You may want to take a look of how I am setting the a webview cookie at :

[Android WebView Cookie Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem/58645816#58645816)

Where in my answer you could see how I'm handling this like:

```
val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
cookieManager.acceptCookie()
cookieManager.setCookie(domain,"$cookieKey=$cookieValue")
cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(view.webViewTest,true)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24457769)

Comment: Hey @AndriiOmelchenko thanks for the tip, I'm quite new in this thing of trying to answer the people here... I've editer the comment, better now?

Comment: IMHO - yes, now its better.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna throw another way how this can be done. Not saying it is the best, but it is a way. You can use JavaScript to set cookies as well. Just override `onPageFinished` in `WebViewClient`

```
new WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {

                val javascript = """document.cookie = "key=$value""""

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    view.evaluateJavascript(javascript) { s -> Timber.d("Inject: %s", s) }
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:" + javascript, null)
                }
        }
}
```

One thing with this approach: you will have to reload the webView. If anyone knows how to fix that, please comment.

Comment: you can use `webview.loadUrl()` for that