# carry forms authentication cookie over from HttpClient (webapi call) to WebView

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication, android-webview, httpclient

I have created an android app that is using a custom-rolled authentication method by calling a web service (webapi on .net mvc 4) with HttpClient.  When the user is authenticated, the action method on the server is setting the forms authentication cookie and then returns a user model back to the android client.  That user model contains the internal user id and a few other properties.

After the user is authenticated, I'm opening up a WebView on android to serve up a viewport for some simple navigation elements.  That WebView needs to be handed the authentication cookie from the webapi call in the previous step.  I assume that the forms authentication cookie is being held in the HttpClient (though I can't confirm this) and if so, is there a way to pass that cookie over to the WebView so the web page that is served up in the WebView knows who the user is based on the first step?

If this isn't possible, can someone guide me with some steps to make this work.

TIA

Comment: This appears to be a very similar question. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716898/set-a-cookie-to-a-webview-in-android

Comment: ya that helps.  If you want to write that up in an answer, I'll mark it as correct for you.

Comment: Great stuff - glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a very similar problem. [Set a cookie to a webView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716898/set-a-cookie-to-a-webview-in-android).

Hopefully this can assist you.