# Application can create webview's cookie?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In our app, click links call webview. so, i need to transfer some data to webview.
I think 'cookie' will be help us. but i can't find good guide.

App can create cookie for webview?
if possible, it can contain all type of datas? or limited?

I don't know web well.
please help me!

P.S.
I don't know ios, too.
it's policy is same to android?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38112838/11647620

Comment: @UsamaAltaf thanks, but i can't know how to 'transfer' data to webview.
i want 'insert data' to cookie, or 'create cookie from nothing'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)If you have cookies then you can insert cookies into your webview.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
            } else {
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
            }
            for (String parse : cookie.split(";")) {
                //  System.out.println("==parse== "+parse);
                cookieManager.setCookie("your_url.com"), parse);
            }
Map<String, String> abc = new HashMap<String, String>();
            abc.put("Cookie", cookie);
webView.loadUrl("your_url.com", abc);
```

2)App cannot create cookies for webview. but webview can create cookies for your App.

```
String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie("your_url.com");
System.out.println("==cookie== "+cookies);
```

I think it will help to understand the web & cookies concept. If you have query just let me know.

Comment: You mean, app can't create cookie from nothing. but if cookie already exist, then app can insert data to cookie and return it?

Am i understanding right?

Comment: Yes, you can't create cookie from nothing

Comment: thanks! And, can i see documentation of cookies? I don't know limit of it. Cookie can contain just string? or every objects, such as dictionary and list?