# Send data to page loaded in WebView

Tags: android, post, webview, http-post

I have a WebView in my app and I load http://mysite.com/somepage.php

I know I can pass data using the GET method because that would just be right in the URL string. I was wondering how I could pass data to the page using the POST method. I tried searching but I cannot find anything specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a method called `postUrl` in `WebView`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);

    String url = "http://mysite.com/somepage.php";
    String postData = "postvar=value";

    webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));
}
```

If `base64` didn't work, try `BASE64` alternatively.

Hope it will works fine.

Comment: you're the man! That works perfect. Much easier than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471581/android-webview-post and it works. What if I want to add more than one post value?

Comment: neither "base64" nor "BASE64" are character sets that are guaranteed to exist. what you should do is String postData = "name=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"); And the use getBytes

Comment: encodingutils deprecated. do you have any other solutions

Comment: How to recive post data in webview?