# Android webview.postUrl(url,Encodingutils.getBytes(postData,"BASE64")) removing "+" from the postdata String

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I am posting from a Webview to the https server as shown in the below URL with BASE64 as charset.

[Send data to page loaded in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218167/send-data-to-page-loaded-in-webview)

My postdata string is a Base64 encoded string with "+" in it.

When i am posting in the way as shown in the above URL, server log shows postdata string with a  missing "+"

I should be able to post any data string from the Webview because i will be posting a Base64 Encoded string on which i don't have control.

Please help me solve this issue.

**Update**:I even tried like this

```
String postData = "fileContents=" + fileCon;

 mWebView.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes());
```

But still "+" is removed from postData when it is posting.If there is no "+" in the postData, it posts correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` is a special character in URLs and represents a space. You need to URL-encode the parameter value before sending it.

```
String postData = "fileContents=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileCon, "UTF-8");
```