# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String() in Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, base64

I am developing a Java EE application in which I need Base64 Encoding/Decoding

So I added `commons-codec-1.5.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` folder of my application and used

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

in the Java file.

During compile time, when I type `Base64`, it shows `encodeBase64String` method is available. But during runtime it is throwing an exception like this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String
```

I have the JAR in the buildpath, but still I don't understand why it throws me the above error.

Comment: Post how you are calling this method.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

That method was [introduced](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5B%5D%29) in Commons Codec 1.4. This exception indicates that you've an older version of Commons Codec somewhere else in the webapp's runtime classpath which got precedence in classloading. Check all paths covered by the webapp's runtime classpath. This includes among others the `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`, `YourAppServer/lib`, `JRE/lib` and `JRE/lib/ext`. Finally remove or upgrade the offending older version.

---

**Update**: as per the comments, you can't seem to locate it. I can only suggest to outcomment the code using that newer method and then put the following line in place:

```
System.out.println(Base64.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

That should print the absolute path to the JAR file where it was been loaded from during runtime.

---

**Update 2**: this did seem to point to the right file. Sorry, I can't explain your problem anymore right now. All I can suggest is to use a different `Base64` method like `encodeBase64(byte[])` and then just construct a `new String(bytes)` yourself. Or you could drop that library and use a different Base64 encoder, for example [this one](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/).

Comment: Thanks for the reponse BalusC.I searched my whole system for this jar.I could not find any old jar anywhere in my system.All i have is a commons-codec-1.5.jar in my Webapp/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I updated my answer with a code line which should give you further insight as to where the `Base64` class is actually been loaded from during runtime.

Comment: @BalusC-the above System.out.printed the following                                                      file:/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/Project_name/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar

Comment: That is plain weird. I'd have guessed that you were using Glassfish 3.0.x which has version 1.3 in its lib, but I see that you're actually using Tomcat 7.0.x which shouldn't have any Commons Codec in its lib. Right now I can't suggest anything else than just using another method or to replace Commons Codec Base64 by a different Base64 encoder/decoder implementation.

Comment: By the way, which JARs do you have more in your `/WEB-INF/lib`? Perhaps one of them is repackaging Commons Codec. Even though I'd have expected that the code source location would have returned it..

Comment: @BalusC-I was using Sun's encoding previously.I came through this [doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html). Then i changed to apache commons-codec.I will try with the above and let you know.

Comment: Another strategy to pinpoint if its same class thats being picked or a different one is to use reflection to print out all public methods of Base64 class.

Comment: @BalusC- i have the following jars in the WEBINF/lib: activation.jar,aspectjweaver.jar,axis.jar,classes12.jar,commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar,commons-codec-1.5.jar,commons-collections-3.2.jar,commons-dbcp-1.3.jar,commons-digester-1.8.jar,commons-discovery-0.4.jar,commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,commons-pool.jar,jaxrpc.jar,mail.jar,saaj.jar,servlet.jar,webserviceutils.jar,wsdl4j.jar

Comment: I don't recognize any which could have repackaged codec. But that `servlet.jar` definitely doesn't belong there. Remove it. Tomcat has already its own.

Comment: @BalusC-I cleaned and build the project.Then i deployed my WAR into tomcat.Interestingly it started working fine.Please see this another question of mine regarding java [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687100/org-apache-http-util-encodingutils-getbytespostdata-base64-removing-from)

Comment: @BalusC, that line of code gives a null pointer error. anyway how can i access encoder and decoder methods in Base64.class, I am using eclipse and it can't locate those methods

Answer (score 6):

Some Google tooling such as GWT has an embedded version of commons-codec with a pre-1.4 Base64 class. You may need to make such tooling JARs inaccessible to your code by refactoring your project such that only the parts of your code that need that tooling can see the dependency.

Answer (score 6):

@Adam Augusta is right, One more thing

Apache-HTTP client jars also comes in same category as some google-apis.

**org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.2.jar**
and **commons-codec-1.4.jar** both on classpath, This is very possible that you will get this problem.

This prove to all jars which are using early version of **common-codec** internally and at the same time someone using **common-codec** explicitly on **classpath** too.

Answer (score 2):

Download  [this jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonscodec17jar.htm)

It resolved my problem, this is 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with JBoss 4.2.3 GA when deploying my web application. I solved the issue by copying my commons-codec 1.6 jar into C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\lib

Comment: This solved my problem. I am using JBoss 5.1.0 GA and deploy a EAR on this server. I need the commons-codec 1.6 for an api included in the project. The JBoss server has a commons-codec 1.3 jar in his lib folder. I want to deploy all libs needed by my project in the ear, than this error occurs. When I copy the commons-codec 1.6 in the lib folder (the old one still exist), it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need the **Apache Commons Codec library** 1.4 or above in your classpath.
This library contains Base64 implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Try add 'commons-codec-1.8.jar' into your JRE folder!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an object of Base64 and use it to encode or decode, when using *org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64* library

## To Encode

> Base64 ed=new Base64();
>
> String encoded=new String(ed.encode("Hello".getBytes()));

Replace "Hello" with the text to be encoded in String Format.

## To Decode

> Base64 ed=new Base64();
>
> String decoded=new String(ed.decode(encoded.getBytes()));

Here encoded is the String variable to be decoded