# Android Studio java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with an imported library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, static-methods, android-runtime

I imported the commons-codec-1.10.jar following the next steps:

1. Under de app directory created a libs directory
2. Copied manually the .jar inside the libs directory
3. Right click the .jar inside android-studio and clicked Add as library

Added this line in my build.grade

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

In my class I imported the library like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Then I tried to access the encodeBase64String static method inside Base64 like this:

```
public static class DoThisThing {
    public String DoThisOtherThing() {
        String hashed = "hello";
        String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(hashed.getBytes());
        return hash;
    }
}

public class ActivityThing extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_thing);
        String hash = DoThisThing.DoThisOtherThing();
        System.out.println(hash);
    }
}
```

Nothing wrong there, even when I compile, except when I run the app, it throws the following error and the app shuts:

```
11-03 09:41:27.719 2390-2476/com.myproject E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method encodeBase64String([B)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
```

My DoThisThing class is not inside the activity by the way, it's just to make it short. I checked the library an indeed the encodeBase64String is static. So I don't know exactly what to do, I'm new in the java and android environment . So any help would be much appreciated

Comment: this might help you <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688644/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-commons-codec-binary-base64-encodebase64>

Comment: Omg thanks. This seems helpful. I'll let you know what I get doing that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

for

```
android.util.Base64
```

And update your method like this.

```
public static class DoThisThing {
 public String DoThisOtherThing() {
    String hashed = "hello";
    byte[] data = hashed.getBytes("UTF-8");
    String hash = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return hash;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Android framework includes ancient version (1.3) of commons-codec library on a classpath. In runtime, it will use its class instead of the one that packaged with your app. `Base64#encodeBase64String` method was introduced in 1.4 and therefore you're receiving the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception.

One possible solution will be to change the library's namespace by repackaging it using [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/).

See my [blogpost](http://blog.osom.info/2015/04/commons-codec-on-android.html) that explains the issue in more detail and shows how to repackage the library.

Answer (score 2):

Well just to tell everyone, I wasn't able to solve this problem. I used the native android library to encode and decode which is in the android.util.Base64

```
            String hash = Base64.encodeToString(hasheado.doFinal(json.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT);
```