# How to open URL from Android application and post values to the URL?

Tags: android

I am newbie to Android development, can you please help me for below scenario

1. From Android native application
2. Open url into browser, along with
3. Post some values to that page

Share me if you have test code.

Answer (score 0):

To have a browser shown in you application with URL, you could use webView in your application. It can take a URL as its input.
You could refer to the document on the Android developers site for the usage:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

And there is also an example available:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Comment: Hi Berby, thanks for quick reply. it is working fine in weview. As per my requirement, open the URL into Android device browser and how to POST values into that page? thanks - sri

Comment: Hi Siri, not sure what kind of post you need. You may find some useful information here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471581/android-webview-post