# opening a web from my android app, post values

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to go to a website from my android mobile, this website accept some POST values.

When I do the same from my computer, is a form with php:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="scripts/pago.php">
```

I can open a website with this code:

```
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

It opens the browser without problem, but, how can I add the post values?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Webview POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471581/android-webview-post)

You can use a webview to open the webpage and then make a post request. Explained at the link given above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
public void postData() throws Exception {


 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xyz.com");

 List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

 list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","ABC");

 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));

 HttpResponse r = client.execute(httppost);

}
```