# Open a browser intent using action POST on Android

Tags: android, rest, post, android-intent

How to set action to POST on opening a browser using intent

Here's my current code:

```
Intent browserIntent;
browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471581/android-webview-post).

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid , it's not possible with the browser. However you can achive it using `Webview` and its `postUrl()` method.

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
String post_Data = "username=uname&password=pwd";
webview.postUrl(url,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```