# android webview, post url loading other url

Tags: android, json, url, post, webview

I would like to post a json data to "url" and after that I would like to load "other url" in webview. After first "url" post with json the "other url" content should change.

Here is what I have done.

```
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(jsonPostData, "base64"));
  webView.loadUrl(mainUrl);
```

Could anyone give me some advice what should I do ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471581/android-webview-post) will help.

Comment: what happen if post is successful ?