# setting Cookies in WebView android

Tags: android, cookies

I'm trying to set some cookies on my `WebView` to open a browser with the same session that I have on my app.

I read a lot of answers but they don't work for me. The only solution I've found is in the `loadUrl`, hardcode the cookie data in `extraHeaders`, but as expected this only works for this requests, and doesn't maintain the session.

The code that I have is:

```
CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
cookieManager.setCookie("http://xx.xxx.example.com","mid="+MySession.GetSession().sessionId+" ; Domain=.example.com");
cookieSyncManager.sync();

String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie("http://xx.xxx.example.com");

Log.d(LOGTAG, "cookie ------>"+cookie);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TuWebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl("http://xx.xx.example.com");
```

`getCookie()` returns the correct data, but when I read the cookies from the server, those are empty. What is wrong? Please advise. 
Thank you!!!

Comment: question helped more than answer. Great.

Comment: My working code and the approach to the compilation of the query
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32189400/5261591

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved!!!! the problem is with the webView, I dont know what happend, but If I create the

```
WebView webView = new WebView(Activity.this);
```

it works. If I read the webview from activity with `findViewById()` it doesn't work.

Also if you need to set a list of cookies that you received previously from a website. 
All you have to do is use a `for-loop` to go through and set all of them . It helped me to solve the situation

Comment: So with way working ? Your answer is not clear to me, can you explain it ?

Comment: well alex I don't know why, but If you take the webView with findViewById doesnt work, if you create the webView manually and add to layout works.

Comment: @flipper83 I'm facing the same problem now.. can you explain with details what you exactly did?

Comment: for me it was working with findViewById() btw thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

```
CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
...
cookieSyncManager.sync();
```

is the cause of problem. You should do like this:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
...
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

And there will be no need to manually create WebView...

Comment: this CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext()); helped me somehow. I was passing some different context to cookie sync manager. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: can this makes the cookies available to normal web browser as well for future use??