# Android WebView disable keyboard predictions

Tags: android, webview, autocomplete, keyboard

I've been scouring the web for hours now looking for answer to these two questions, to no avail.

1. How do I disable all keyboard auto-complete suggestions within an app/activity/WebView? Most answers focus on scenarios that include an EditText, but in my scenario, there is just a WebView with input fields.
2. In the scenario described above, how do I keep the keyboard open all the time I am in the activity containing the WebView? Pressing the "Done" button on the keyboard makes the text field lose focus and the keyboard collapses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For your first requirement

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" // Add this Manifest section
```

For your second requirement

```
webviewOBJ.clearFormData();
webviewOBJ.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
```

**[setSaveFormData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSaveFormData(boolean))**

> Sets whether the WebView should save form data. In Android O, the
>   platform has implemented a fully functional Autofill feature to store
>   form data. Therefore, the Webview form data save feature is disabled.

You should read **[Android Webview private browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9838963/3395198)**

Comment: `Pressing the "Done" button on the keyboard makes the text field lose focus and the keyboard collapses` Didn't try yet

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in manifests file inside your web view activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```