# How to disable input autosuggestion inside android webview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-webview, webviewclient

I have a Web-View showing some inputs and it is working fine ,except when the inputa are clicked, a google credit card autosuggestion is popping, I must remove this option and i could not find a solution,

[provided image with the unwanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZA0a.jpg)

i tried this post -[Disabling autosuggestion on WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404798/disabling-autosuggestion-on-webview)
   but none of the suggested answers helped me, please help

my webView

```
    if (webView == null) {
        toolbar_container.show()
        toolbar_group.show()
        toolbar_tv.text = getString(R.string.credit_card_info)
        webView = NoSuggestionsWebView(this)
        val webSettings = webView?.settings
        WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this)?.clearFormData()
        webSettings?.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSettings?.savePassword = false
        webSettings?.saveFormData= false
        webView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#061a3e"))
        webView?.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this) { result ->
            val dialog =
                OneButtonDialog(
                    activity = this@MainActivity,
                    type = OneButtonDialog.LOAD_CARD_FAILED,
                    message = result
                )
            dialog.show()
        }, "Android")
        webView?.layoutParams?.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        webView?.layoutParams?.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        fragment_container.addView(webView)
        webView?.loadUrl("My_URL")
        showProgressBar()
    }
    webView?.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            dismissProgressBar()
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think your problem is solved in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206289/android-webview-disable-keyboard-predictions?rq=1) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404798/disabling-autosuggestion-on-webview)

Comment: thanks, but i already tried that

Comment: and didn't work,,?

Comment: no, i created a wrapper to WebView as suggested and other suggestions are depreceted