# Set cookie android webview

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview

I want to set cookie in a webview in android and i have no logged user instead. The user is correctly logged in the android application. This is my code:

```
            WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
            setContentView(webview);
            final WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

            webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                    "cookie", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


            String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);

            String[] cookies = cookie.split(";");

            final HashMap<String, String> cookieStrings = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (String cook : cookies) {
                String[] cs = cook.split("=");
                cookieStrings.put(cs[0], cs[1]);
            }

            CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

            webview.loadUrl(url,cookieStrings);
```

Comment: so what does the above code result in?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5396965/4385913) or this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem)

Comment: the result is a webview with no logged user instead of application (web view also) on the same domain