# Using cookies from httpclient in webview

Tags: cookies, httpclient, webviewclient

In my app I'm sending a device ID to a server using http post and I'm getting a session ID back. Now I need to get the session cookie in my webviewclient. I did some research and found this:

[Android WebView Cookie Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem)

The problem is the solution doesn't work for me. I keep getting an error on this line:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

The method getCookieStore() is undefined for HttpClient type. I should have all the right libraries loaded, so I don't know why I keep getting an error.

Here is my code, maybe someone will be able help me implement a solution to get the session cookie into my webview.

Thanks in advance!

```
package mds.DragonLords;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Home extends Activity {


WebView mWebView;

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private String tmDevice;
    private String sid;
    private String url;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


         tmDevice = "2" + tm.getDeviceId();

         postData();


        url = "myserver"+sid.substring(5); 


        setContentView(R.layout.web);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myserver");
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", tmDevice));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

   }

    private void inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
                total.append(line); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sid = total.toString();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into the same thing. I know it's an old post, but maybe it'll help somebody else.

The problem is in declaration of postData().

That line now is :

`HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();`

It should be:

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

see this: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html