# Cookies shared between WebView instances in different processes?

Tags: android

Do WebView instances in my process share cookies and cache with WebView instances created by other processes?

Say I have my website www.example.com, and there's a login page there. If the user logs into my site from the native browser app, then they come into my app later on where I have an embedded WebView instance, will their login cookies still be present? Or do they have to login again?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a possible answer may reside [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem).

Answer (score 0):

The user will have to log in again, the cookies used by the native browser are not accessible to your webview.