# Android Orientation change WebView, Cookies need saving

Tags: android, http, cookies, webview

I'm working on an application in which a user is automatically logged in to a website. However, on orientation changes the WebView will now save and restore its state in `onSaveState()` and `onRestoreState`. The only problem is that the cookies  associated with the website are not stored and I cannot find a way to properly save the cookies now.

The target version of Android is 2.1. Any help or advice is welcome.

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
cookieManager.setCookie("www.example.com", name + "=" + value + ";");
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

**NB!** Give the Android enough time to proccess cookies. [Source](http://www.walletapp.net/android-passing-cookie-to-webview).

**EDIT**

Broken link: [source](http://code.walletapp.net/post/46414301269/passing-cookie-to-webview)

Comment: http://code.walletapp.net/post/46414301269/passing-cookie-to-webview is this right link?