# Android Webview Cookies aren't accepted

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

first of all I'm sorry for my bad english, i hope you understand me.

My code is running absolutly bugless in the Android 2.3 VM etc.
I've got the problem that my via JS ( jQuery ) set cookies aren't accepted in Android 4.x.

How I set Cookies via jQuery:

```
$.cookie('test', 'blabla', { expires: 999999, path: '/' });
```

My Java source:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
this.getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); mWebView =
(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

if(cm != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&   cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()){ 
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); 
} else {
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
} 

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance(); 
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
mWebView.loadUrl("URL HERE");
```

I really hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: Do you get any error (logcat)?

Comment: No, i don't get any error. I forgot to tell, I'm loading the URL from file:// , could this create the problem?

Comment: I don't know to be honest :(, but this one seems familiar with your question, I would say, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem