# getting trouble to set cookie android.webkit.CookieManager

Tags: android, cookiemanager

i have login to a site through WebView. then i have get cookie which is set by the webview at login time. then i have tried to set the cookie later. please see my code:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

Log.e("checkPost 1", cookie);
cookieManager.setCookie("https://************", cookie);

Log.e("checkPost 2", cookieManager.getCookie("https://*************"));
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
Log.e("checkPost 3", cookieManager.getCookie("https://*************"));
```

in `checkPost 1` printed cookie shows that it is fine. but in `checkPost 2` and after `sync()` it by `CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();` statement, the `checkPost 3` shows that most of the cookie is vanished. what is the problem ? i need to set the cookie. but i could not find a way spending about 2 days.

**Edit:**

in android documentation it says that:

> public void setCookie (String url, String value)
>
> Sets a cookie for the given URL. Any existing cookie with the same
>   host, path and name will be replaced with the new cookie. The cookie
>   being set must not have expired and must not be a session cookie,
>   otherwise it will be ignored.

is there any way to force `CookieManager` set session cookie via `setCookie()` ?
i think the problem is, may be i am trying to set `session cookie`

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem/15772246 -- is there a difference between your question and that post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know there is any answer or not for my question. but for my purpose i have use another way to solve my problem. it's a long process, but it works. i have given up the idea to save `session cookie` in `CookieManager` (which is not possible by the document of Android Developer site). So, what i have done is: i have converted the session cookie in string and save them in memory. for later use i just take the string from memory and convert it back to session cookie.

**Edit:**

(For negative voters) I have told in my answer that the process is too long, like 4-5 classes. and this project was my first project in android so the codes are too messy. all the class is full of too much code. so it is impossible to post it here. i have told the process i have used. so why negative vote?

i have converted the session in my own way and build the string to session in reverse way.

if there is any way i would post the answer. it take me about 15~20 days to build the classes and algorithms. so why not you do some Google and find a better way, or just simply build your own algorithm and process like mine. i have told the key part here, you just need to find a way to implement it into code. Thanks

Comment: -1 for no code to actually show this. How do you "convert it back to a session cookie"? Are you setting HTTP headers?