# How can I store cookie in webview?

Tags: android

The webview of my app won't store cookie so that I have login again if I restart my app.

To store cookie, what should I add to this codes?
Can anyone show me with code using my original code?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    private SimpleSideDrawer mNav;
    WebView myWebView;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://example-site.com");          
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
    .....
    }
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can store the cookie and retrieve them on app start like expline here 
[Android WebView Cookie Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem)

Comment: Could you show me how with my code? I'm sorry. I'm new to android so that I want to know how it goes on my code

Comment: the first answer in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem can resolve your problem