# How to send a HTTP POST request with a cookie attached in WebView?

Tags: android, asp.net, webview

I am using WebView in Android. My ASP.NET Server set a cookie in WebView which is used to track user. Every thing works fine. Now I need to send an explicit HTTP POST request to server with the same cookie. Is it possible?

Comment: the CookieManager handles your webview's cookies.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem

Comment: @njzk2, I need to send a HTTP POST request to server without using WebView? Can hyou post some code?

Comment: @npace, It is not working? Can you try it in a sample app?