# How to Logout from Instagram in Android?

Tags: android, authentication, instagram, logout

I logged in Instagram using browser. I want to logout from the Instagram. How can i archive programmatically?

Comment: browser or third party library ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below code to clear cookies of browser to make it logout

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(ogout.this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 4):

You can use this library for login,for logout just call `mApp.resetAccessToken();`

https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth

and for webview.use below properties for clearing webview sessions and data.

```
    WebSettings mWebSettings = webview.getSettings();
        mWebSettings.setSavePassword(false);
        mWebSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
```

or  reset HTTP Session using

```
  android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```

or

```
     CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

[How to clear cookies and cache of webview on Android when not in webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998241/how-to-clear-cookies-and-cache-of-webview-on-android-when-not-in-webview)

Comment: removeAllCookie is depracated