# Unable to send the cookie. Maximum number of cookies would be exceeded

Tags: android, magento, cookies, android-webview, magento2

Android Web view is giving me **"Unable to send the cookie.Cookie size would be exceeded"** error. The website I am opening in the web-view url is build using Magento 2 e-commerce platform.
I have googled about the same and found out that [Magento 2 throws an exception if your cookies size is more than 50.](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/84)

And [this](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/) link gives me a clear comparative listing of cookie size as well as cookie limit supported by different browsers and Android supports only 50 cookies per domain.

As per the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910378/android-magento-2-e-commerce-website-not-working-in-android-webview), i am clearing the cookies whenever getting this error but the problem is , it also clears my cart items as they are saved in browser cookies.In this situation, end user have to re-select all the cart items which is a bad user experience.

Screenshots of my error message is below -

[image]

[image]

How to solve this issue. Any help is appreciated.