# Clear search results from web view

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

How can I clear search results from `WebView`? I used `clearFormData()`, `clearHistory()` methods but when I click on search field on https://google.com it shows me my previous search results.
[image]

UPDATE: The answer i've received clears history but not clears search results.

Comment: Did you try to clear coockies?

Comment: yes, not working.

Comment: What is Kotlin tag here for?

Comment: @AntonA. because somebody who use kotlin for android may know the answer. just to receive more feedback

Comment: @NazariyMoshenskiy no, it is not language specific quastion

Comment: it's android specific question. kotlin is related to android. I added all tags which relate to my question. more precise tags == better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was `WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();`. Only this clears previous search results.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to clear the cookies via the CookieManager. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31950789

Comment: @AntonA. no, because I wrote it in my code and it didn't worked.