# Pass cookies from native login to webview

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview, httprequest, android-cookiemanager

I am following [**this**](http://blog.winfieldpeterson.com/2013/01/17/cookies-in-hybrid-android-apps/) for sharing cookies from native code to `WebView`. I have a native login screen. On successful login I am saving the cookies in `CookieSyncManager`. And when the webview loads, I am passing those cookies to it so that the login screen does not appears.
Following is what I have implemented :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //Setup Cookie Manager and Persistence to disk
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
}
```

**HttpRequest for login** :

```
private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = getDefaultClient(); // new DefaultHttpClient();

        syncCookiesFromAppCookieManager(loginUrl, client);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = null;
            try {
            instream = entity.getContent();
              } catch (IOException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            response = convertStreamToString(instream);
            response = StringUtils.remove(response, "\n");
            syncCookiesFromAppCookieManager(loginUrl, client);
           // client.setCookieStore((org.apache.http.client.CookieStore) new PersistentCookieStore(context));



}
    }
```

And in **WebActivity** :

```
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();  
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

But I am again getting the login screen on `webView`. i.e. cookies are not getting stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**K7Ko's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem) answer finally worked for me. But only after I commented the line

```
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
```