# How to set cookie in android WebView client

Tags: android, cookies, webview, asynchttpclient

I want to call one specific url via **WebView**. The page can only be called after user already logged in. I use **AsyncHttpClient** library to perform login call. Once after successfully logged in , loading url via **WebView** doesn't seem recognise the proper headers esp cookie. My suspect is that cookies are not sync correctly between **HttpClient** and **WebView's HttpClient** . Any idea why ? . Here is how i use **WebView**

```
    final WebView webView = (WebView) content.findViewById(R.id.web_travel_advisory);
    String url = "http://mydomainurl.com/get_data_after_login";

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Appreciate ur help .

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ohh after several hours, i finally figured it out to get it worked. Firstly [CookieSyncManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html) is deprecated on later version of android since api 21 according to doc. So decided not to use it anymore. Secondly [CookieManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager) is used to store cookie for **WebView**.

**Final code**

```
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    List<Cookie> cookies = WSHelper.cookieStore.getCookies();

    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().contains("session")){
                String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; Domain=" + cookie.getDomain();
                cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);
                Log.d("CookieUrl",cookieString + " ");
            }
        }
    }
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

The key changes to solution is: use **cookie.getDomain()** instead of explicit domain.

```
cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);
```

Comment: up voting since you mention about giving the cookie domain name instead of the server domain that the webview is about to load. this solved my issue

Comment: @Tixeon could you tell me what libarary i need to inport for this to work ?Android studio keeps complaining about List<Cookie> .Furthermore, can i specifically mention the domain name ?how?Does this saves the cookies and reuse it if when we close and re open the app ?

Comment: what is WSHelper??

Comment: @AdamKis You can get your saved cookies from somewhere else.

Comment: not useful at all not mentioned why we can't get List<Cookie> of cookies

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, after few changes works for me:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity{
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    String token="";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webviewpage);

        mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    public void LaunchWebView(View view) {

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebView, true);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String token2= mPreferences.getString("auth_token","");

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("x-auth-token", token);

        myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl("YOUR_URL", map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was slightly different, but answer from @Tixeon gave me the key to solve it. I was composing my Cookie and adding it to the WebView request, but I discovered that Android was overriding my Cookie and sending its own Cookie.
So first of all, I had to remove all cookies from the array, then compose my own Cookie. This is the sample code:

```
// Note that my project has minSdkVersion 21, so I can directly use methods only available in Lollipop
private fun loadUrlInWebView(url: String) {
    webView.settings.apply {
        builtInZoomControls = false
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        useWideViewPort = true
        loadWithOverviewMode = true
        setSupportMultipleWindows(false)
    }
    CookieManager.getInstance().apply {
        setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true) // My minSdkVersion is 21
        removeAllCookies { value ->
            Log.d("Cookies", "Removed all cookies from CookieManager")
        }
    }

    webView.apply {
        isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
        isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = true
        loadUrl(
            url,
            mutableMapOf(
                "Cookie" to "ThisIsMyCookieWithMyValues",
                "Accept" to "*/*",
                "Accept-Encoding" to "gzip, deflate",
                "Cache-Control" to "no-cache",
                "Content-type" to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Now the request contains my Cookie and not the default one provided by Android, and my session in WebView is working. Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

Latest way to set cookies using cookieManager

```
val siteCookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(“https://www.dummyurl.com”)
cookieManager.removeSessionCookies {
    if (! siteCookies.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        val cookie = siteCookies.split("; ".toRegex())
            .dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() } as ArrayList<String>
        val iterator = cookie.iterator()
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            val cookie = iterator.next()
            if (cookie.isNullOrEmpty()) continue
            cookieManager.setCookie(“https://www.dummyurl.com”, cookie)
        }
    }
}
```

posting this if this helps someone.

Comment: Be sure to answer in the same programming language. The question regards Android Java whereas the answer is for Javascript. However, ideas are welcomed :)