# Set cookies in Android WebView

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview

I know there are a number of questions related to this topic but none of them has worked for me.

I have a `String` that contains some cookies in the form `key=value; key=value; ...`. 
My app:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webView);

        configWebView();
        loadCookies();
   }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    void configWebView() {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                 Map<String, String> requestHeaders = request.getRequestHeaders();
                 return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
            }
        });
    }

    void loadCookies() {
        // Do things
        loadPage(cookies);
    }

    void loadPage(String cookies) {
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

        for (String cookie : cookies.split(";")) {
            cookieManager.setCookie(DOMAIN, cookie.trim());
        }
        cookieManager.flush();

        webView.loadPage(URL);
    }
}
```

I don't see the result I'm expecting and if I inspect the content of `requestHeaders`, I see there are no Cookies passed to the server.
What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120508/how-to-set-cookie-in-android-webview-client

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to `cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);` but it still doesn't work

Comment: What is value of `DOMAIN`? is it same as `cookie.getDomain()` ?

Comment: `DOMAIN` is something like `google.com`, I'm using it for something like `mail.google.com`. `cookie` is just a `String` in my case so I don't have a `getDomain` method