# Android javascript cookie doesn`t work in webview

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, webview

I am trying to write android app with WebView. When I am setting cookie from webView with javascript its not working.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

index.html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Meta-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.cookie = "userName=Vasya";
            console.log("cookies:");
            console.log(document.cookie);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

console output:

```
11-01 17:35:16.239 26866-26866/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "cookies:", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (9)
11-01 17:35:16.242 26866-26866/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (10)
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120508/how-to-set-cookie-in-android-webview-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using localStorage

`localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
localStorage.getItem('foo')`