# Cookies with WebView

Tags: java, android, cookies, webview

I'm creating an Android app embedding just a browser displaying a website, using `WebView`:

```
mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { ... }
});
mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

I noticed two strange things:

- I get a message like "Cookies are disabled"
- When I click on links that should display PDF files, nothing happens (but no error message)

**How to enable features like cookies and opening (or at least downloading) PDF files?**

Comment: You should have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [gist of a small app](https://gist.github.com/Cheticamp/1cc49914877731c819f3421c52896724) that demonstrates how to enable cookies in WebView and how to download/open a PDF file.

Note that the app demonstrates two ways of opening a PDF file. The first way opens the PDF within WebView; the second way opens the PDF in an external app if one is defined for PDF files.

It is important to remember that `WebView` does not offer full-blown browser-like support. From the [documentation for WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> **Basic usage**
>
> By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine; the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it, and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a WebView.

Google continues to refine `WebView`, so you will want to keep abreast of [changes](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/managing-webview.html). In addition, Google continues to address the security of `WebView` and, for instance, will no longer support OAuth requests originating from a `WebView`. See [this](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html).

Comment: Thanks. The PDF download thing works, but the cookies thing still doesn't. I tried everything: `CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();`, and then  `cm.setAcceptCookie(true);     cm.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mywebView, true);` either after the `mywebView.loadUrl()` or before, it's the same "Sorry but this browser doesn't accept cookies" :(  (it's a Wordpress wp-login.php page)

Comment: @Basj Glad the PDF download is working. Are you getting the cookie error message from WordPress? Could it be something like [this](https://www.steckinsights.com/how-to-fix-a-cookies-blocked-error-on-wordpress-admin-dashboard/) going on? What is your test environment (API/device)? Have you tried accessing a different site that requires cookies to see if they are blocked there as well?

Comment: @Basj Another thought: Check any browser that you might be using and make sure that cookies are turned on. In Chrome, look under "Settings."

Comment: Your link in a previous comment (about Wordpress solution) was ... super useful @Cheticamp, and solved the cookies problem! Many thanks!

Comment: @Basj Good to hear.