# How to manage http(server side) session in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

in my application I'm having three activities where first activity is for an intro, 2nd one is login/register and the third one is webView. how can I manage the session between all three activities? when someone login in login activity server will send the JSESSIONID in the cookies. how to use that same JSESSIONID and set it to webView cookies.
I'm using volley JsonObjectRequest

Answer (score 0):

**How session can be managed in andorid:**

One of the way for session management in android is by `Cookies`. 
The flow is simple, Whenever the User is successfully logged in then in response of that login API call you will get a Response Header named `set-cookie` which is the newly generated sessionId by the server. You can save it in `SharedPreferences` and then on every next API call `Headers` send that same cookie by the key `cookie` and the `value` that have saved in `SharedPreferences`.

**How you can set the cookie to WebView:**

In your case you have a `WebView` that you want to set the Cookie so check this link:

> [Android WebView Cookie Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem)

**How you can get and Set the headers in Volley**

check this link:

> https://github.com/google/volley/issues/37